# With :hover effect changes the height of the block. How to make it not to "push" the lower blocks?

Tags: html, css, hover

I can not find the right solution. There are cards with goods, go in rows on the Flex. When you hover over them, the information block is added to the card and the block increases in height. And when this happens it pushes the lower blocks, which should not be. How to win in this situation?

Poked through absolute, but all past..

Here is an example code:

```css
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  margin-right:5px;
  background-color:#efefef;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.btn {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hover {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .hover {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>One
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div>  
    </li>
    <li>Two
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
    </li>
    <li>Tree
  <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
    <li>Four
  <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
    <li>Five
  <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give an example of how you want it to look when the div is expanded - I don't see how you can show that hover text without pushing the below blocks down, unless you absolutely position the p - but then where would you put it?

Comment: so what do u want exactly when u hover on block?

Comment: I need it to work like this.
http://prntscr.com/kwinlu

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Using visibility to hide elements means they still take up the same amount of space, unlike display:none; which collapses the space

```
.hover {
  visibility:hidden;
}

li:hover .hover {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Option 2: Fixing the width and height on the li so that the content inside doesn't expand them. You can play around with the height and width of the li that you want

```
li {
  margin-right:5px;
  background-color:#efefef;
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
}

.hover {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .hover {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list, try nested divs like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.child {
  margin-right:5px;
  background-color:#efefef;
  border:1px solid red;
  min-height: 5rem;
  min-width: 3rem;
}

.btn {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

span {
  display: none;
}

.child:hover .hover > span {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">One
    <p class="hover"><span>Contant</span></p>
    <div class="btn"></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="child">Two
    <p class="hover"><span>Contant</span></p>
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
    </div>
    <div class="child">Tree
      <p class="hover"><span>Contant</span></p>
        <div class="btn"></div> </div>
        <div class="child">Four
      <p class="hover"><span>Contant</span></p>
        <div class="btn"></div> </div>
        <div class="child">Five
      <p class="hover"><span>Contant</span></p>
    <div class="btn"></div> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this problem. I duplicated all the content in the hover box. When hover, I hide all the content and show the new one in absolute.

```css
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  margin-right:5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#efefef;
  border:1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hover-box {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 100%;
  border-right:1px solid red;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  left:-1px;
  z-index:100;
}

li:hover .hover-box {
  display:block;
}

li:hover .btn1 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>One - sample
    <div class="hover-box">
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> 
    </div>    
    <div class="btn"></div>  
    </li>
    <li>Two - sample
    <div class="hover-box">
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> 
    </div>    
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
    </li>
    <li>Tree - sample
  <div class="hover-box">
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> 
    </div>    
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
    <li>Four - sample
  <div class="hover-box">
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> 
    </div>    
    <div class="btn btn1"></div> </li>
    <li>Five - sample
  <div class="hover-box">
    <p class="hover">Contant</p>
    <div class="btn"></div> 
    </div>    
    <div class="btn"></div> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```